# Wordpress: Display the content on an other page of the pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i need to display the_content() on an other page of the pagination of a post. E.g. the first page is an extra field called 'index'. Page 2 is 'Abstract' and page 3 shows author informations. On page 4 the_content should start.

The problem is that wordpress starts counting the pages and on page 4 the_content is shown as if it would on page 4 (so after 4 times of < ! -- next page -->).

I did this:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (!preg_match('#/\d+/?#', $url)) {
    the_field("index");
} elseif(false !== strpos($url,'/2/')) {
    get_the_author_meta('first_name').' '.get_the_author_meta('last_name');
} elseif(false !== strpos($url,'/3/')) { 
    the_field("abstract");
} else {
    the_content();
}
```

But, as i said, the_content() starts as if it would be page 4. I know it should act this way. 
How can i do that page 4 is like page 1 for the_content().

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFY:**

I want to put out the_content() in my theme file *content-single.php* to display my article in the front end. I have pagination active so Wordpress paginates my article whenever it finds a < !-- next page -->. That's native Wordpress behaviour.

But i want to put some extra content BEFORE the_content().

```
Page 1: Index
Page 2: Abstract
Page 3: Author
Page 4: START the_content() page 1
Page 5: the_content() page 2
Page 6: the_content() page 3
```

and so on...

I'm doing this with the code i wrote above. I check on which page we are. ($url,'/3/') is page 3.

Even if i check for page 4 (in the else-part) and put out the_content() here wordpress puts out page 4 of the_content(), so the part after 4 times < !--next page-->. I doesn't START with the_content() on page 4 but it start on page 1 but doesn't display it. The internal page counter runs some how.

How can i start the_content() on page 4? Or how can i prevent Wordpress from counting the pages?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing i've noticed is that you're using regex to match page's number ! you should use only [$page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) (a WordPress-specific global variable).

> $page (int) The page of the post, as specified by the query var page.
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

However i suggest using a shortcode, much easier than editing `single.php` and gives more flexibility.

```
[section page='index'] // obviously you need to build a custom shortcode

<!--nextpage-->

[section page='abstract']

<!--nextpage-->

[section page='author']

<!--nextpage-->

<!-- page's 1 content -->

<!--nextpage-->

<!-- page's 2 content -->

<!--nextpage-->

<!-- page's 3 content -->
```